# How to read dynamic html input variables in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML form, with inputs fields I need to be transferred to `PHP` as variables. This works. But in the same form, I have an HTML select dropdown function, which dynamically creates a new input field, if a specific option is selected. I can't get the data from the new input field into `PHP`.

**This is the HTML:**

```
<div validate-input" data-validate="Input1">
<input type="text" name="Input1" placeholder="Input1">
</div>

<select name="Category">
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option value="Input2">Input2</option>
  <option value="Input3">Input3</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    if ($('select option:selected').text() == "Input4") {
    $('labe1l').remove();
      $('html select').after("<label1> Input data4 <input></input></label1>");

    } else {
      $('label1').remove();
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

**And this is the PHP:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $Input1 = $_POST['Input1'];
    $Input2 = $_POST['Input2'];
    $Input3 = $_POST['Input3'];
    $Input4 = $_POST['Input4'];
?>
```

**Question:**

> It is data from Input4 that is not transferred to `PHP`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You seem to have a typo `labe1l` in `$('labe1l').remove();`

Comment: Does your new field have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Additionally I don't even see `Input4` in your HTML code! And `Input2` and `Input3` are values, not input fields that will be submitted to PHP.

Comment: Your new input field doesn't seem to have an id/name. So how do you get it's value?

Comment: If I ad a id or name, it wont generate a new input field. What is the correct format?

Comment: I think it doesn't work bcz you would have nested quotes like: "...id="..." ..."

Comment: But take a look at this: timerElem.innerHTML =
                    "<div class=\"card days\"> \<div class=\"numbers\">" + days + "</div>days</div> \<div class=\"card hours\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + hours + "</div>hours</div> \<div class=\"card minutes\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + minutes + "</div>minutes</div> \<div class=\"card seconds\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + seconds + "</div>seconds</div> \</div>";

Comment: You should ad your id, name, and other attributes in the same way

Comment: And the label shouldn't include the input. It should be like: <label>....</label><input>....     **There is no end of input, so u can't use </input>**

Comment: So   $('html select').after("<label1> Input data4 </label1><input>");    ?
But there is no way for me to attach a id or name attribute?

Comment: $('html select').after("<label1>Input data4</label1><input name=\"Input4\" id=\"Input4\" >");

Comment: Like in the example above (that one with a lot of div-s)